# Unity Can Not Reference Any *.dll Files In Apple M1 Max (macOS 13.1 - 22C65)

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, dll, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I have Unity project which can be open and build in windows 10. But I can not open the project in Apple M1 Max (macOS 13.1 - 22C65). I try Unity sentinel and Unity Intel. The problem is all *.dll files can't be referenced. I use package which usually used, like facebook sdk unity, odin inspector, etc. I'll give error example for odin inspector , this error also happen in another package :  `The type or namespace name 'Required' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`. `Required` is from Sirenix.OdinInspector. In windows 10 there is auto reference for any *.dll files :

[image]

But in mac,
there is no auto reference for any *.dll files :

[image]

I can reproduce the error in windows by uncheck the auto reference. So maybe my problem can be solve by auto reference the *.dll files in mac. So my question is why auto reference menu is no appear in unity mac ? How to add auto reference in mac like in windows 10 ?

Comment: why have you marked it as editor only?

Comment: @BugFinder it's example for odin inspector , and I want it only in editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can fix it by clone using lfs